# Set CWND max size in Linux

Tags: networking, configuration, selinux, tcpdump

I've used this command below in Solaris to set the max CWND window size:

```
ndd -set /dev/tcp tcp_cwnd_max size_here
```

But I don't know the equivalent of it in Linux. Can anyone help me please? Note: I want to set the max size not the initial one. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: this is probably not a good stackexchange community for this question. We tend to focus on Ubuntu-specific things here.

It's not really my area, but as far as I know, linux doesn't let you set (max) cwnd size directly. Instead, cwnd size is a function of write buffer size, which you can set by writing to `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem` or per-socket with `setsockopt`. If you want really big cwnd sizes you need to set another option called 'window scaling' or something. Look at `man 7 tcp` for more info.